# When and how did Professor X bring sentinels in the X Mansion?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

At the end of X-Men Apocalypse, there was a training session for X Men in which they had to fight sentinels. However, at the end of X Men Days of Future Past, sentinels were just there and Magneto left.

When and how did Professor X manage to bring sentinels into the X mansion? Where were they when X Mansion was accidentally destroyed by Alex Summers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my understanding, they are in the [Danger Room](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Danger_Room). And chances are that the are virtualised sentinels.

It is also not the first time that we have seen this scenario. In X-Men : Last Stand, we see Wolverine and the X-Men train younger mutants against sentinels in the Danger Room.

> A Sentinel briefly appears during a training session in the Danger Room. After Colossus launches Wolverine into the air, he cuts off the head of the Sentinel with his claws. The head falls through the air and lands in front of the X-Men. It is later revealed to have been an interactive hologram.

[Source](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Sentinels)

[image: Scene from Last Stand]

Comment: Doubtful that they are virtualized. That's 1983 we are talking about, not the 2005 of X-3.

Comment: @cde based on the technology shown in Cerebo during that time, I find it likely. Also, you can see that it is more primitive than the 2005 as the room is not a virtual battle field.

Comment: the small model of Cerebro was built by Hank in 1962 as shown in first class. and the cerebro in DOFP and Apocalypse is an scaled model of that cerebro.

Comment: @AJ I know but I am using to as a point of reference for the technology that the X-Men had available to them at the time.

Comment: Looked at the history of holography. It was discovered in 1949 and used in 1962, so virtualization can also be possible. But it is also possible that Beast has built them as he also built the danger room, cerebro etc.

Comment: @AJ my other question still stands though, if they are real, why fight them inside, in a relatively small room. Instead of outside where the grounds are quite open and expansive

Comment: if they are real, wouldn't it create problem for other people or mutants

Answer (score 2):

If you consider it's 10 years later, and Hank McCoy has been shown to be a genius in electrical and mechanical engineering among other things, it's simply likely that **Beast built them**. After all, Magneto did have the blue prints on microfilm, when he stole them in 1973 as seen in DOFP.

Hank of course, built Cerebro, as well as the Blackbird (that exploded in Apocalypse), as well as Havoc's suit, Cyclop's sunglasses and visor, etc.

Mainline production of the Sentinel program had Government funding scrapped in 1972 prior to DOFP, and then Trask's company was shutdown following the end of DOFP, including Sentinel production. Unless it was started up again, but consider that the general world sentiment was that mutants are okay, or at least not a threat, that's not likely.

Also consider it's 1983, they have not yet gotten the technology to build a holographic Danger Room as seen in the old timeline X3 (set in 2005), so it's likely real robots.

Comment: But then why not fight them outside? Instead of a small room?

Comment: @david because downstairs is the X-men compound, and upstairs is the regular school. Xavier likes to keep those separate for obvious reasons.

Comment: There are instances where training is done above ground for the X-Men. Cyclops shooting clay disks for example.  I understand what you are saying but fighting multiple sentinels in a small room seems even more unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

My answer might be vague but consider this.

1. The sentinels were decommissioned and Moira MacTaggert was Professors friend and most likely Charles did not erase her memory again.So maybe Government connections
2. Or are you asking how he managed to fit in the sentinels in the mansion.Well there was a huge warehouse where they store the jet so maybe we have not seen the other huge parts of the mansion.(as David Pilkington said in another answer)