# Robots at the end of X-Men: Apocalypse

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In [*X-Men: Apocalypse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Apocalypse) (2016) at the very end of the movie, while they are showing the newly assembled X-Men in a brief Ewok celebration, there appear several metallic robots. What are those and why are they in that scene?

Comment: Related [When and how did Professor X bring sentinels in the X Mansion?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53555/when-and-how-did-professor-x-bring-sentinels-in-the-x-mansion)

Comment: Is this title alone a little bit of a spoiler?

Comment: @ToddWilcox : No.  Or, if so, only in a very minor way.  It's referring to an after-credits scene that is designed to pitch an idea for people to gnaw on after the movie, and is really quite unrelated to the bulk of this particular movie.

Comment: @TOOGAM its not an after credit scene. It's the epilogue, before the credits.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The scene at the end of the movie is showing the rather famous X-Men "Danger Room"; we have not seen very much of it in the movies, but it appeared in a regular basis in the source comics, especially early on.

The robots were Sentinels, as you can read about in [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53555/when-and-how-did-professor-x-bring-sentinels-in-the-x-mansion), who are programmed to attack mutants. The purpose of the Danger Room is to train X-Men to fight against life-threatening foes in a controlled environment. The "threats" in the danger room, most of the time, are not real. They are created by Professor X to *simulate* real-life threats the X-Men might face. As such, it's likely that the Sentinels are just copies of, or even holographic/virtual projections of, actual Sentinels.

The point of the scene was to show that Xavier had finally decided to accept what Raven and Hank had been telling him -- that his school needed to be more than just a place to educate mutants. He needed to train them to fight, and become X-Men.